# how to download file by urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

i know how to download simple file from urrlib2.urlopen

but my end URL is not simple it has special character in it :

" **www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A Mathematician's Apology.pdf** "

special character *Mathematician's*   **'** is in this path

some how i know that

http://www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A%20Mathematician%27s%20Apology.pdf

is url i have to use to download file 
but if i don't have this kind of end URL with me every time

please give me solution so that i can download file which has special URL

i have basic method that can be used but i don't know how to use this

1. urllib.quote(string[, safe])
2. urllib.quote_plus(string[, safe])
3. urllib.unquote(string)
4. urllib.unquote_plus(string)

please help me with this method by example

thank you

Comment: As a side note, " www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A Mathematician's Apology.pdf " isn't a URL. Besides the extra spaces, it's missing the scheme. (Well, actually, it's a relative URL off the base, so if your base is "http://example.com/foo/", it validly specifies "http://example.com/foo/ www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A Mathematician's Apology.pdf"… but I doubt that's what you want.)

Comment: Also, you've tagged this both 2.7 and 3.x, but `urllib` doesn't have any such methods in 3.x. (`urllib.parse` has similar methods, but they don't do exactly the same things.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like this?

```
filename = url.split('/')[-1]
cleanurl = urllib.quote(url)
urllib.urlretrieve(cleanurl, filename)
```

Comment: `cleanurl` is going to be just `A%20Mathematician%27s%20Apology.pdf`, which won't be very useful.

Comment: No, the whole url is quoted, which gives me www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A%20Mathematician%27s%20Apology.pdf

Comment: Of course if he gives an actual URL (with a scheme and everything) `urllib.quote(url)` will quote things you don't want, like the `:`.

Comment: it also give me error in last line but thank you because urllib.quote(url) is working as some part of this but it is not complete solution

Answer (score 0):

You want to quote only the path component of the URL, not the whole thing.

The cleanest way to do this is to split it into pieces with [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse), quote the path component, and rejoin the whole thing.

But as it turns out, `urlparse` automatically quotes the path anyway. This isn't really documented, but it's been true for every version so far, so if you're willing to rely on that, it's as simple as this:

```
>>> url = "www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A Mathematician's Apology.pdf"
>>> url = urlparse.urlparse(url).geturl()
>>> url
'http://www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A%20Mathematician%27s%20Apology.pdf'
```

---

If you actually just have a host and path, you can in fact just use `urllib.quote`. With a full URL, that will quote the `:` character between the scheme and host, but if you don't have a scheme, as in you example, that's not a problem. (Of course it will quote the stray spaces in your example too… but those are going to be a problem no matter *what* you do, so your first step has to be removing them.)

```
>>> url = " www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A Mathematician's Apology.pdf "
>>> url = urllib.quote(url.strip())
>>> url
'www.math.ualberta.ca/mss/misc/A%20Mathematician%27s%20Apology.pdf'
```

You'll still need to add a scheme before this is actually useful, of course.

Comment: thank you but it give same result as input. it is not replacing special character

Comment: What special character are you referring to? It replaces the spaces and the apostrophe, with the same `%20` and `%27` sequences that you have in your expected output, at least in Python 2.7.2 and 2.7.5.